# Mouse not working in WINE applications under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, mouse, wine

I've searched every place I could think of, but nobody seems to have had this issue or didn't bother asking about it.

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 freshly with the gnome fallback shell. Everything works perfectly fine, except for one thing.

My WINE applications start on the wrong screen, this isn't really a big issue, but when I drag the window to my main screen, the mouse doesn't work on the application anymore. The app doesn't freeze, and is fully responsive to keyboard input, I just can't click on anything anymore.

My specs (relevant):
- NVidia Geforce 540M
- 1 laptop screen 1366x768
- 1 Samsung Syncmaster SA550 27" - 1920x1080

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried deleting it and installing it again? Wine won't offer the promised quality and performance anyway. It depends on the application you're running too, by the way.

Comment: I'm trying to run World of Warcraft. When I disable my laptop screen, everything works, at least, it looks like it. But in fact, when I switch to fullscreen, the app just crashes. When I stay in window mode, about 50% of the screen isn't clickable. - same problem as described in my question.

Comment: That's why. World of Warcraft's performance would never be the same if you're using Wine.

Try using a windows virtualized machine with VMWare or VirtualBox. Installing windows would be the best though, but I don't think Wine would work at all.

Comment: Appearantly, it had something to do with the current version of Wine. I've seen more reports about this, but unfortionately, there's no fix.

Here's what exactly happens:

If you open your Wine Config window, drag it for 50% to your other screen, so 50% of the window is on screen 1 and 50% on screen 2. Now, click on an element like a dropdown menu or a button on the non-responsive screen. Surprisingly, you'll see the side of the window on screen 1 updating, but screen 2 doesn't. How and why this is happening, I don't know.

Back to Windows I guess :/

Comment: I hope we get an answer to this, as I'm a user of Wine too, and I need higher quality, so +1 for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the application on a resolution smaller then the current on your pc?

If so, do the following (I have a laptop with 1366x768 on the internal monitor and 1920x1080 on the external monitor):

- Open winecfg
- Check the Virtual Desktop checkbox and set the size to the largest resolution you are going to use
- Start the app and check if it's working properly now (You can check that with the battlenet launcher :))
- Start winecfg again and uncheck the Virtual Desktop box